# Highlight recently created by*ngFor element in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have a list of `Word`s, shown or hidden by `*ngFor` according to their `hidden` property.

Please check [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iWe60iUNcplB9rm7h1I9?p=preview).

The problem is that when there are a huge amount of words in list, it is difficult to find where the new one appeared. So I would like to highlight them.

My idea was to set a `.highlight` class by default and to remove it after item was added, with smooth `transition`:

**HTML**

```
  <div 
     *ngFor="let item of words | shownWords" 
     [ngClass]="{'item':true, 'highlihted': item.hidden}">
     {{item.value}}
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
    background-color: #ffffff;

    transition: background .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background .3s ease-out;
}
.item.highlihted {
    background-color: #ea90aa;
}
```

**Unfortunately** this doesn't work, as new item is already created without `.highlight` class.

So, here is the question: **how to detect when a new item was added and which item exactly was added?** Is it even possible? Or may be there is another way to achieve what I want?

P. S. please tell me if I attached incorrect plunker or something else wrong with my question.

### Solution

First of all sorry for incomplete description, I forget to mention that I want to **switch off a hightlight after a while.**

Please check @Boyan Kostadinov's answer and then return here for a final solution and **[final plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dy3Y3wGvv3Jg3kH6FVvN?p=preview)**:

new `toggleHidden()`:

```
toggleHidden(item:Word) {
    item.hidden= !item.hidden;
    if (!item.hidden) {
        item.highlihted = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
           item.highlihted = false;
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: By "how to detect when a new item was added and which item exactly was added?" do you mean which item was clicked to be shown? You have the item that was about to be shown inside the "toggleHidden" function, under "if (!item.hidden)", you can output it with console.log(item). I don't understand what you are trying to do I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you what you want: http://plnkr.co/edit/QxvCte7SvYg3hljBPIlB?p=preview

Explanation:

Added new "highlighted" property to your words class:

```
export class Word {
    value:string;
    hidden = false;
    highlihted = false;

    constructor(value: string) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Changed the toggleHidden function:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  pipes: [ShownWords],
  template: `

      <h2>Click on a word above line to show/hide word below line:</h2>
      <div *ngFor="let item of words" (click)="toggleHidden(item)">{{item.value}}</div>
      <hr>
      <div 
         *ngFor="let item of words | shownWords" 
         [ngClass]="{item:true, highlihted: item.highlihted}">
         {{item.value}}
      </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  words: Word[] = [new Word('one'),new Word('two'),new Word('three'),new Word('four'),new Word('five')];

  toggleHidden(item:Word) {
    this.words.forEach((w:Word) => { w.highlihted = false });

    item.hidden= !item.hidden;
    if (!item.hidden) item.highlihted = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see I missed a bit with question description, but here is what I really wanted: http://plnkr.co/edit/Dy3Y3wGvv3Jg3kH6FVvN?p=preview (inspired by your solution)